# NSFetchedResultsController not displaying correct sort until after saveContext saves?

Tags: iphone, sorting, random, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Admittedly I'm new. Criticism welcomed.

After a month of trying various tweaks, the problem remains.  For simplicity: There are three view controllers, calling them A, B, & C.
A has 2 round rect buttons that each do a push segue to B.
B is a tableview filled in by the troublesome 'NSFetchedResultsController' described.  B has a Nav bar button (Add) to segue to C which accepts two data fields and saves the new item then pops View C and shows View B.

Adding new item from View C and returning to View B results in a correctly sorted list.  But if I return from View B back to View A, then segue again to View B, the list is not sorted correctly.  Each time View B appears it creates a new Fetched Results Controller.  Back to A, Back to B the view is not sorted correctly.  Repeat - same problem.  But return back to A, *wait 3 seconds*, and then segue to B and woohoo the list is sorted correctly.  I've tried it with the cache set to nil, and set to a value that is deleted when the view disappears.

Every subsequent new display of View B will show the list correctly sorted.  The wrong sort sequence only occurs in the sequence described above - after adding 1 item, going back one view and then redisplaying the table view fed by the FRC.

Questions and suggestions are welcomed.  Thanks in advance.  The rest of the original question is shown below;

I've a `NSFetchedResultsController` filling a table view in alphabetic order, with a segue to another view to add an item. When I return to the main table, the sort is random. I can exit from the view to a prior view on the hierarchy and reload the view and it will still be randomly sorted. I can repeat this several times in succession. However, if I wait a few seconds, and follow the same steps, the view will sort correctly. It appears that the correct sort happens when reading from the saved file, which I understand happens "sometime later" automatically. Cache is set to nil.

I have a `saveContext` call and then a `reloadData` call to the table view in the method that adds an item, trying to force the data to save and then reload the table.  I have the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` set to the view.

Any suggestions?

The code for the Fetched Results Controller is as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Player"];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor * lastNameSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor * firstNameSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: lastNameSort, firstNameSort, nil];

    NSFetchedResultsController * frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    frc.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![frc performFetch:&error]) {
        //  Handle the error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = frc;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
} 

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:  
  (NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type   {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     Player * player = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = player.fullName;
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:
     (id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:   
      (NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break; 
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: What do your delegate methods look like?

Comment: And is it actually random, like completely different each time?

Comment: Which delegate methods do you want to see.  I want to avoid being one of those newbees who post pages and pages of code and ask:  What did I do wrong.  Let me know which ones you think are relevant.   The order is different each time.  Newly added items appear in the middle of the table, even though the sort field contains all As or all Zs.  I've tried various efforts at forcing the fetchedResultsController to be re-created when the view appears or after saving the context, but nothing is fixing the bad sorting.  Except: going back up the view stack to the prior view and then segueing..

Comment: The `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods